# Load More Data on click till the length of list

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of dataList |slice : 0:3">
    <mat-checkbox">{{data}}</mat-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
   <div>
    <button id="loadMore" >showMore</button>
   </div>
```

I want to display 3 more data on click and should display  till the length of list,on per
click 3 data should show then on click 3 more data should show till the end of list.

Comment: Ideally these should be handled in the back-end. Where you pass the no of documents to be skipped and also the limit.

Comment: what is the step if we have to do frontend

Comment: What is that asterisk doing there `*ngFor=""`

Comment: Jonathan - The * is a shorthand for using the new Angular template syntax with the template tag. This is also called a structural Directive. It is helpful to know that * is just a shorthand to explicitly defining the data bindings on a template tag. The template tag prevents the browser from reading or executing the code within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally these should be handled in the back-end. Where you pass the no of documents to be skipped and also the limit.

You need to add skip and limit to the array you have fetched. I am assuming you are using the latest angular version, so your component.ts should look like

```
dataList: Array = [1,2,3,4,...];
appendedArr = [];
skip = 0;
limit = 3;

loadMore(skip, limit){
  this.skip = this.skip + skip;
  this.limit = this.limit + limit;
  appendedArr = dataList.slice(this.skip, this.limit)
}
```

you can call this function onInit as well, or once you have fetched the whole array passing skip and limit as 0, `loadMore(0,0)`

And then call this function on button click in html file

```
<div>
<button id="loadMore" (click) = "loadMore(3,3)" >showMore</button>
```